# In iOS block how to modify variables outside without using __block

Tags: ios, block

I read that if block wants to modify a variable outside, this variable has to be described by using keyword `__block` since it has to be copied to heap with block itself.

But what if I do not want to use `__block` and still get to modify the variable, is there a way?

I did some thinking that maybe I can set that variable to `global` or `static` instead of an `auto` one so that it will be stored in static memory area.

Or can I set it to pointer and point to some content which is allocated on heap? I tried this case which didn't work, I would like to know why.

Comment: What do you mean be "must be" and "has to"? What are you trying to avoid exactly? It does not have to, but it might help with performance

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert, my understanding is that, for future use, ARC would automatically copy block with its variables onto heap, otherwise both block and its variables would be released on stack.

Comment: Yes, you can modify outside global or `static` variables inside the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, in order to avoid losing the variable, block would copy the local variable onto heap if you would like to access and modify the variable. But if you make the variable global or static, which would be stored on global region and you don't need to worry losing it on stack, block wouldn't copy it but is able to modify it directly.

Please correct me if any mistake and I will mark myself answer if there isn't any better one.